# Spring Integration recommended way of enriching events with key based queries

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

I want to read from data from Kafka, and on each event, read from MongoDB with the Id and another field from the Kafka event. I wonder in general what is the recommended way to do this, and whether it is possible to do this with the `ReactiveMongoDbMessageSource`. I thought that maybe the right operator is `.gateway()` or `.enrich()` but I'm really not sure. I don't really have a clue about how to use this with a message source so I'm not sure that it's even possible. I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```java
    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return from(reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.receiveAutoAck()
                        .map(GenericMessage::new))
            .<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>transform(ConsumerRecord::value)
            .gateway((message) -> enrichMongoDbPayloadByMessageKey(message.getHeaders().getId())
            .handle(new ReactiveElasticsearchMessageHandler());
    }
```

I'd really like to see an example for a mock implementation of my needed `enrichMongoDbPayloadByMessageKey()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gateway()` or `enricher()` is right direction, depending on your requirements if you'd like to continue the flow with only a result from the MongoDb request, or you want to add more data to the result of that `transform()`.

The `ReactiveMongoDbMessageSource` is a wrong direction here just because it is used as a source of messages - the beginning of the flow. In your case it is really a service activator based on the result received from the Kafka.

There is no (yet) reactive MongoDb gateway (request-reply channel adapter), but the closest out-of-the-box solution is a `MongoDbOutboundGateway`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-outbound-gateway.

If you really wish to deal here with reactive solution, consider to implement the service method which would receive your arguments, perform a reactive operation on the MongoDB and return you something. See for that goal a `ReactiveMongoTemplate.findOne(Query query, Class<T> entityClass)`.

There is no the `gateway()` operator with a signature you show.
It is also wrong to use `message.getHeaders().getId()` since it does not reflect anything you receive from Kafka.

See more docs about gateway and enricher:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-gateway

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher

Comment: I don't quite understand the difference. You've said: "if you'd like to continue the flow with only a result from the request, or you want to add more data to the result of that `transform()`". What `transform()`? Aren't both of the options `request-reply` based?  I'd be glad to implement a `ReactiveMongoOutboundGateway` with my team & maybe contribute, but I need a reactive outbound gateway for example. I've seen r2dbc's (is there anything else?) that extends `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`, so I guess that I also need to extend this base. Am I right?

Comment: You have some `transform()` in your flow to extract data from the Kafka record. That’s what I’m talking about. You have there some data which you’d like to use to query something from MongoDB. And from here we need to understand if you to add more info to this or is it ok to replace it with the result from the MongoDB. Yes, that R2DBC message handler is a good sample how to implement a reactive outbound gateway. Yes, it has to be that reply producing extension: the framework doesn’t care what you reply - simple data or reactive type - it still a reply to produce. See docs for R2DBC also

Comment: My use case is indeed a payload enricher, what class should help me then? If I understand correctly the `ReactiveMongoOutboundGateway` isn't really relevant to me because it replaces the message that has been received with the message that returned from the parameterized query. The [payload enricher docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher) aren't JavaDSL friendly & don't include external interactions anyway. Do you know of any examples of external enrichment? What class needs to be implemented?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/spring-integration-enricher) was pretty hard to understand. If you can write a small sample for how you'd enrich from MongoDb, it would be super helpful to me.

Comment: You cannot use enricher for your scenario. Looks like `ConsumerRecord::value` is just plain `String`. And this type is immutable and there is no properties on it to set. You need to revise your design if you are thinking about adding data to the result from the Kafka consumer. The main goal of the enricher is to request data from other service and set a reply into a property of the current payload. This is not your current data is for.

Comment: I see. But what if I’ll create an object? I just want to understand how the enricher works. Should I use some `ReactiveMessageHandler`? Or would it be a gateway? What is the class that needed to be implemented?

Comment: I want to query Mongo for every Kafka message that I get, and enrich the message with some properties from the reply. Of course it will be done on an object and not on a string.

Comment: See `EnricherSpec.requestSubFlow()`. There you can use a `handle()` and call your `enrichMongoDbPayloadByMessageKey()`. You cannot use a `ReactiveMessageHandler` for this goal since it is a one-way. Its `Mono<Void>` is nothing to about the value. Also I'm not sure what kind of MongoDb query would return `void`...

Comment: But are there any guidelines for `enrichMongoDbPayloadByMessageKey()`? Is there any interface for enrichment class?

Comment: That is a POJO method which can be called from the service activator with a payload. The result of the method should be produced to replyChannel header to be returned to the enricher for property setting. How you implement that method is up to you.

Comment: See more info about service methods in messaging in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#service-activator.